# Failed Upgrade tool

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-8.04

I have an old server which runs on ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy). I need to upgrade it to the latest release. When I issue the do-release-upgrade command, I am getting the following error. I am clueless on what to do! Any help in this is appreciated.

```
root@server:~# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading
extracting '/tmp/tmp2qqi4S/intrepid.tar.gz'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 45, in <module>
    fetcher.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/UpdateManager/Core/DistUpgradeFetcherCo
re.py", line 160, in run
    if not self.extractDistUpgrader():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/UpdateManager/Core/DistUpgradeFetcherCo
re.py", line 98, in extractDistUpgrader
    tar = tarfile.open(self.tmpdir+"/"+os.path.basename(self.uri),"r")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/tarfile.py", line 1148, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/tarfile.py", line 1209, in gzopen
    fileobj = file(name, mode + "b")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp2qqi4S/intrepid.tar.gz'
```

Comment: From 8.04 to 13.04?  I'd seriously consider backup/reinstall/restore instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're talking about trying to upgrade a server that's 5 years behind.
While I'm often quoted as saying "you should not have to put a CD in the drive to do a unix upgrade", this is one of those times where you *really have to put a CD in the drive*.

Trying to drag your server through 5 years of upgrades is a recipe for pain and disaster.

If you read your command output you should have noticed the two rather ominous lines:

```
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
```

This is (probably) because the upgrade tool isn't available anymore.  I'm fairly sure the Intrepid Ibex package repositories aren't available either, so you would need to find a copy of those as well.
The amount of time you would waste on this makes a clean reinstall a far better option.